# Getting error while I specify ajax response for attribute of an angular directive in DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a new directive in Angular1(v1.3.15) and specified a new attribute for it in DOM like this:

`<event-action-choices appointment-action-list="getAppointmentDataForEvent(${intEvent.id})" userbar="${false}" event-id="${intEvent.id}"></event-action-choices>`

Following is the code for my controller and directive

```
module.controller('EventActionDataController', [
'$scope',
'$log',
function ($scope, $log) {


    $scope.getAppointmentDataForEvent = function (eventId) {

            return [{"childId":12,"parentId":11}];
    };

}]);

    module.directive("eventActionChoices", function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    eventId: '=eventId',
    userbar: '=userbar',
    appointmentActionList: '=appointmentActionList',
  },
  templateUrl: $("#baseUrl").val()+'/path/to/eventActionChoices.html',
};});
```

However, I am getting error while calling this directive

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":[{"childId":12,"parentId":11}],"oldVal":

My motive is to get the response of Ajax request from getAppointmentDataForEvent method. However, even the hardcoded response which I am trying to send back is giving me same error.

Comment: look like you have mix angular and jquery! and why you need directive to get ajax call? use angular $http or $resource service! and you used the isolate scope incorrectly. you don't need to transform between the (-) and camalCase. so to solve your errer change to this `appointmentActionList="getAppointmentDataForEvent(${intEvent.id})"`

Comment: No, that is not the problem. You can mention the attribute as I have mentioned. `appointment-action-list`

Comment: try to bind funtion like this then `appointmentActionList: '&appointmentActionList'` not equal sign

Comment: I understood that this was the root cause of the problem because I was not getting the error if I return a string like "abc". I tried with &appointmentActionList too, but could not figure out how to get result of this function. My motive is to get the return result of this function.

Comment: Neither, in controller  nor your directive is calling `appointmentActionList()` at least in the code you posted! you need to use `link` function in the directive!

Comment: look at this [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/DWEzvXrWChtQdunqlhsA?p=preview) I call the function in the `link` function and you can view the console.log

Comment: Can you please specify how can I pass result of a function from a controller to attribute of the directive. Then further I want to read that array in template.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked like charm.